# prepareForSegue compiler error

Tags: ios, swift

I want to scan a QR code (doing this example: http://humberaquino.me/qrcode-scanning-in-swift/), however I have a problem with this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let barcodeViewController: BarcodeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BarcodeViewController

    barcodeViewController.delegate = self
}
```

I got this:

[image: error]

When I change this to `as!`, I'm getting:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on this line.

Comment: Try hitting command + option + shift + K to clean your project. Also you can just do `let barcodeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BarcodeViewController` since saying the type twice is redundant.

Comment: Your BarcodeViewController is a subclass of UIViewController right?

Comment: Right its a subclass

Comment: Did you clean and run the project? Even if it doesn't look like it will let you run just try it. Sometimes xcode can be a little bugy.

Comment: I tried :C No reason

Comment: Check in your storyboard - the destination view controller class should be `BarcodeViewController`.

Comment: And i have view controller called like this

Comment: 1. Show us the `class` declaration of your `BarcodeViewController`... 2. Log `segue.destinationViewController` to see what you're actually getting (and report back).

Comment: Do you have some other segues?

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to always check the `segue.identifier` before doing anything.

Comment: Declaration of barecodevievcontroler: 
class BarcodeViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

Comment: Also segue.destinationViewController is right view controller I don't have any other segue

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one segue on that view controller, it may be another one firing.  checking segue.identifier is one way of making sure you're on the right one.  If the behaviour is based on the class you can do this :

```
if let barcodeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? BarcodeViewController
{
  barcodeViewController.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: now I entering to another ViewController but still no qr code scanning screen :C

Comment: This would seem to confirm the first problem.  You have a segue that's not going where you expected it to go.  So it was originally causing the crash because you weren't checking the destination VC in the event.   Now, it won't crash but that just means you're not executing your code on that (wrong) destination controller.   You need to figure out 1) if the segue that is firing is the one you intended, 2) if it is, then why the destination is the wrong one.

Comment: I repaired it by doing storyboard again